# What's the recommended way to add Javascript libraries to an Asp.Net Core 2 project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm developing a Asp.Net Core 2 project and I want add some Javascript libraries.

With NuGet is easy:

1. Search it in NuGet Package Manager
2. Install
3. Reference ("using" clause)

I read is not recommended use NuGet as package manager for JavaScript libraries. In my research, and lots of abbreviations latter, I heard of WebPack BUT, I dont know exactly how I do this 3 steps (Search, Install and Reference) on Visual Studio.

By example, lets say I want add a simple library, like the [Summernote](https://summernote.org/) to a Asp.Net Core 2 Project, how can I do it?

Comment: There really isn't a currently recommended way that's been "blessed" by Microsoft. They _were_ using `bower`, but as that's been abandoned by the community, MS has removed it from the current templates, without really offering a replacement.  Most people would recommend `npm` or `yarn`, but those don't have any decent integration into VS at the moment the way `Nuget` and `bower` do/did.